# How to make definiton work?

Tags: python, pygame, global-variables, definition

Please see below examples:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
x = 800
y = 600
programDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((x,y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Title')
pygame.display.update()
programExit = False  
while not programExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            programExit = True
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Second Example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
x = 800
y = 600
programDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((x,y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Title')
pygame.display.update()
programExit = False
def programQuit():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            programExit = True
while not programExit:
    programQuit()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

How to make definition from 2nd example work so the outcome is same as in first example?
Think it might be something to do with global and local variables but could not get it working.

Comment: Don't give the parameter of programQuit the same name as the variable programExit

Comment: I have removed parameter but still don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I fixed it

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
x = 800
y = 600
programDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((x,y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Title')
pygame.display.update()
programExit = False

def checkForProgramQuit():
    global programExit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            programExit = True



while not programExit:
    checkForProgramQuit()
    programDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

the `programExit` variable you were modifying was local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Carcigenticate is quite right, but here are some notes on what's going on here and some practices that will avoid this in future.

```
programExit = False
def programQuit(programExit=False):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            programExit = True   # Issue 1

while not programExit:
    programQuit()
```

Issue 1 is that this assignment is creating a new variable in the scope of the function and setting it's value. It is not changing the value of the module level variable programExit.

A better way to do this is to have the function pass back it's result as a return value like this.

```
def programContinue():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return False
    return True

while programContinue():
    pass
```

Also by reversing the boolean logic returned by the function, I think things become a bit clearer and we can get rid of the 'not'. Also expressing the while clause this way seems a bit clearer to me. The 'pass' statement could usefully be replaced with some logging or the display updates from C._'s answer.